# not able to add ###Name### in textarea from jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function addtext(typed) {
  var text_till = $('#ttext').html();
  switch (typed) {
    case 'name':
      var add = "###Name###";
      $('#ttext').html(add);
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="ttext"></textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="addtext('name')">1</button>
```

not able to add special symbols in textarea through function

Comment: kindly check if you have multiple elements having **same id**

Comment: I have checked your code snippet and it seems working fine

Comment: Hi Govi khati, please check if you are coding your jquery function in the $(document.ready()) function.

Comment: Hi @Govi Khatri your code also works fine. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one please...

```
<form>
    <textarea id="ggg"></textarea>
</form>
<button onclick="addText('name')">1</button>

function addText(name){
        var text_till = document.getElementById("ggg").value;
        switch(name){
            case 'name':
                var add ="###Name###";
                document.getElementById("ggg").value = add;
                break;
            default:
        }
    }
```